# Script Math's not correct lua minecraft

Tags: math, lua, timer, minecraft

idk what is wrong but it writes this into the file when it saves the value. If u need more information or have a question please ask me! Thanks for your time and hopefully u your solution!
SebyGHG
My discord: S̸̽̚e̵̓̓b̸̿̕y̴͆͐#4638
Here is a screenshot of the time and the value in the file:
[Value in file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDtX3.png)
[Time in game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oncAS.jpg)

Code:

```
name = "Timer"
description = "Just a normal Timer."
positionX = 0
positionY = 0
sizeX = 24
sizeY = 10
scale = 1

START_STOP_KEY = 0x55 --or 'U'
RESET_KEY = 0x4A --or 'J'
 --
--[[
    Timer Module Script by SebyGHG original script by Onix64(Stopwatch)


    if you wish to change the key you can take the key code from here
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes
]] -------------script-code-------------
state = 1
stopTime = 0
startTime = 0

f = io.input("timesave.txt")
result  = f :read()
f :close()
stopTime = result
state = 2

function keyboard(key, isDown)
    if (isDown == true) then
        if (key == RESET_KEY) then
            state = 0
        elseif (key == START_STOP_KEY) then
            if (state == 0) then
                state = 1
                startTime = os.time()
            elseif (state == 1) then
                state = 2
        io.output("timesave.txt")
        timesave= (io.open("timesave.txt","w"))
                io.write(stopTime)
                io.close(timesave)
                stopTime = os.time()
            elseif (state == 2) then
        state = 1
        startTime =startTime  + os.time() - stopTime
            end
        end
    end
end

TimerText = "00:00"
TextColor = {r = 30, g = 255, b = 30, a = 255}
function doubleDigit(number)
    if (number < 10) then
        return "0" .. math.floor(number)
    else
        return math.floor(number)
    end
end

function timeText(time)
    local result = ""
    local days = 0
    while (time > 86399) do
        days = days + 1
        time = time - 86400
    end

    local hours = 0
    while (time > 3599) do
        hours = hours + 1
        time = time - 86400
    end

    local minutes = 0
    while (time > 59) do
        minutes = minutes + 1
        time = time - 60
    end

    if (days == 0) then
        if (hours == 0) then
            return doubleDigit(minutes) .. ":" .. doubleDigit(time)
        else
            return math.floor(hours) .. " : " .. doubleDigit(minutes) .. ":" .. doubleDigit(time)
        end
    else
        return math.floor(days) ..
            " : " .. doubleDigit(hours) .. " : " .. doubleDigit(minutes) .. ":" .. doubleDigit(time)
    end
end

function update()
    if (state == 0) then
        TextColor = {r = 255, g = 0, b = 0, a = 255}
        TimerText = "00:00"
    elseif (state == 1) then
        TimerText = timeText(os.time() - startTime)
        TextColor = {r = 0, g = 255, b = 255, a = 255}
    elseif (state == 2) then
        TimerText = timeText(stopTime - startTime)
        TextColor = {r = 255, g = 255, b = 0, a = 255}
    end
end

function render()
    local font = gui.font()
    local tw = font.width(TimerText)

    gfx.color(0, 0, 0, 0)
    gfx.rect(0, 0, tw + 4, 10)

    gfx.color(TextColor.r, TextColor.g, TextColor.b, TextColor.a)
    gfx.text(2, 1, TimerText)
end
```

Comment: What's the question? What is exactly wrong? What is the expected outcome?
Also, putting contact information in questions is not the way this website works. All clarifications, questions, comments, discussions and answers are to be put on here

Comment: The expected outcome is a file that stores the time

Comment: That is the time. It's what os.time() returns. it is a [Unix Timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)

Comment: What do you mean exactly

Comment: You may convert the time into human-readable format before saving to file: `local dt = os.date("*t", stopTime); io.write(dt.year.."."..dt.month.."."..dt.day)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I will remade it with my updated version I will tag u there

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff pinged you there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lua timer script producing all-numeric value instead of proper time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70157053/lua-timer-script-producing-all-numeric-value-instead-of-proper-time)

Answer (score 0):

One error I spot is this part

```
while (time > 3599) do
    hours = hours + 1
    time = time - 86400
end
```

this is most likely supposed to be

```
while (time > 3599) do
    hours = hours + 1
    time = time - 3600
end
```

Comment: Thanks do you maybe have an idea whats wrong in the file writing part?