# Lua timer script producing all-numeric value instead of proper time

Tags: math, lua, timer, minecraft

My timer script writes this into the file when it saves the value.

Example Time in file: `1638185640`

Example of time displayed in game:
[image: in game]

```
name = "Timer"
description = "Just a normal Timer."
positionX = 0
positionY = 0
sizeX = 24
sizeY = 10
scale = 1

START_STOP_KEY = 0x55 --or 'U'
RESET_KEY = 0x4A --or 'J'
 --
--[[
    Timer Module Script by SebyGHG original script by Onix64(Stopwatch)


    if you wish to change the key you can take the key code from here
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes
]] -------------script-code-------------

state = 1
stopTime = 0
startTime = 0

f = io.input("timesave.txt")
result  = f :read()
f :close()
stopTime = result
state = 2

function keyboard(key, isDown)
    if (isDown == true) then
        if (key == RESET_KEY) then
            state = 0
        elseif (key == START_STOP_KEY) then
            if (state == 0) then
                state = 1
                startTime = os.time()
            elseif (state == 1) then
                state = 2
        io.output("timesave.txt")
        timesave= (io.open("timesave.txt","w"))
                io.write(stopTime)
                io.close(timesave)
                stopTime = os.time() -stopTime
            elseif (state == 2) then
        state = 1
        startTime =startTime  + os.time() - stopTime
            end
        end
    end
end

TimerText = "00:00"
TextColor = {r = 30, g = 255, b = 30, a = 255}
function doubleDigit(number)
    if (number < 10) then
        return "0" .. math.floor(number)
    else
        return math.floor(number)
    end
end

function timeText(time)
    local result = ""
    local days = 0
    while (time > 86399) do
        days = days + 1
        time = time - 86400
    end

    local hours = 0
    while (time > 3599) do
        hours = hours + 1
        time = time - 3600
    end

    local minutes = 0
    while (time > 59) do
        minutes = minutes + 1
        time = time - 60
    end

    if (days == 0) then
        if (hours == 0) then
            return doubleDigit(minutes) .. ":" .. doubleDigit(time)
        else
            return math.floor(hours) .. " : " .. doubleDigit(minutes) .. ":" .. doubleDigit(time)
        end
    else
        return math.floor(days) ..
            " : " .. doubleDigit(hours) .. " : " .. doubleDigit(minutes) .. ":" .. doubleDigit(time)
    end
end

function update()
    if (state == 0) then
        TextColor = {r = 255, g = 0, b = 0, a = 255}
        TimerText = "00:00"
    elseif (state == 1) then
        TimerText = timeText(os.time() - startTime)
        TextColor = {r = 0, g = 255, b = 255, a = 255}
    elseif (state == 2) then
        TimerText = timeText(stopTime - startTime)
        TextColor = {r = 255, g = 255, b = 0, a = 255}
    end
end

function render()
    local font = gui.font()
    local tw = font.width(TimerText)

    gfx.color(0, 0, 0, 0)
    gfx.rect(0, 0, tw + 4, 10)

    gfx.color(TextColor.r, TextColor.g, TextColor.b, TextColor.a)
    gfx.text(2, 1, TimerText)
end
```

Comment: I think you forgot to say what specifically the problem is, is the code not supposed to write to the file? is teh value wrong? if the value is wrong, what is an example of the wrong value and an example of what you expected it to be?

Comment: So it counts the time that i spent in a world. Then save the time in a txt. If i quit the game and relaunch it it should read the file and apply the time.

Comment: @Nifim it calculate the wrong time when it reads the file

Comment: @Nifim links to screens : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DBYY9eKq8uaviS0W8JGQ44ZR4y2a8zPD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Nifim and https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iYLFo8IWqPY8eeaWtUdcniN0JUXZ3J9z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: add this information to your question. and ideally embed the screenshots, if the screen shots are just of some text just type the text out.

Comment: @Nifim ok i will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are saving the Unix Timestamp to your file, you can try and make it human readable using an online time converter (https://time.is/Unix_time_converter)

Besides this, take some time to read the os.time() implementation details on this lua page: https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html

> The time function, when called without arguments, returns the current date and time, coded as a number. (In most systems, that number is the number of seconds since some epoch.)

If you want the time in between certain action, save the initial timestamp and diff it at the end of the action. This is natively supported in lua using os.difftime(). (http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.difftime)

Comment: I will try to fix my problem with the information you sent me thanks!